# convert executable 2008 to dll

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, dll, executable

I have a question about converting a C# 2008 console application that is currently run as an executable to be run as a DLL instead. I do not know what parts of the entire solution file should be part of the dll file and what parts (if any) should remain as an executable.

I was briefly advised by a contract shop that when the current application calls a web service, that portion should become the dll. I was also told by the contract shop that the chelper.cs code (that calls the web service) should be part of the dll.
 This same contract shop also said I could  write separate dlls for each 'type' of method that is called. If I did that, I would use portions of code from each project file.

So basically I have part of one project file out of 4 project files that should be included in the dll file?

Here is a description of the current project files:
1. one project file has various routines that are tied with the web service.
2. Another project file is a handshaker to verify security.
3. There is the 'driver' project file.
4. There is a 'sample' code project file that was written by the contract shop that supports the web service.

Can you tell me how you would decide to setup the application I listed above as dll file(s)? How would you

change the code that I just listed above? How would you setup the code tio convert it (use it) as a dll file?

Comment: Please select some answers to your previous questions. Thanks :)

Comment: Is there a way to say someone answered my question successfully? How can I vote to say I accept the correct answer someone gave to me?

Comment: There should be a check mark you can click next to there post.

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing your code and project structure, the best advise I can give you is to refactor by logical functions. In a small and typical application this would be:

1. Application/UI/Presentation Layer (application related logic and operations)
2. Business layer (where business logic resides)
3. Data layer (where data access operations occur)
4. Interface layer (where interfaces to external systems are occur)
5. Service layer (where you expose your business services to external clients)

So if you have any method, class, etc. that falls under a layer above, I would tag those as candidate to put in it's own project.

Another way to organize is by domain or namespace (after organizing per above). But that would depend a lot on the details of your application so I leave that for you to decide.

Note that whether your organization is "correct" depends a lot on your architect's guiding principles.